# Mock a specific constructor

Tags: mockito, powermock, powermockito

mockito-1.10.19 
<s>powermock-mockito-1.7.1</s>

powermock-1.7.4
junit 4.12

I have a class that has multiple constructors (java). Once constructor calls the other. I want to mock only 1 of the constructors (the one that is called from the other). I cannot change the code unfortunately - I am just testing it. Here is the class to be tested:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.connection;

public class Foo {
    public Foo (Connection connection){
        this(connection, new File ());
    }
    public Foo (Connection connection, File file){
       // do stuff
    }
    // other methods
}
```

Here is the test class I have written:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.connection;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Matchers;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.legacy.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {
        Connection mockConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
        Foo fooObj = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withArguments(Matchers.notNull(), Matchers.notNull()).thenReturn(fooObj);

        Foo newFooObj = new Foo (mockConnection);
        assertNotNull ("newFooObj should not be null", newFooObj);
    }
}
```

The problem is that Foo(Connection) is not being entered. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with the latest 1.7.x version of Powermock (1.7.4) and it works as you wanted it to. So you might just need to upgrade a few minor versions.

Comment: updated powermock but still no dice! Still not getting into the single parameter constructor :(

Comment: Strange since I definitely observed the bug and the fix. The only difference in my code was that I'm using the `notNull()` matcher (that takes no arguments). You should also double-check that your dependency manager (maven, gradle, etc...) is not pulling in an even more recent version of PowerMock. PowerMock 2.x versions are branched from an earlier version of the code that had the bug you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for you help @goolie. I am manually using the Powermock stuff and all the versions are 1.7.4. I changed mine to Matchers.notNull(). Still not passing. I will keep looking.